# Geometry Object geoprecessing fails

Tags: python, arcpy, geometry, geoprocessing, results

Theoretically, ArcPy geometry objects can be used as inputs and / or outputs in geoprocessing tools, just pass `arcpy.Geometry()` as an argument for outputs. However, I have come across several tools (coincidentally, they tend to have optional outputs) that when entering `arcpy.Geometry()` as output, they do not return any object but ignore it and write the output 'in_memory'. For example [CostConnectivity](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cost-connectivity.htm)

Examples of these tools:

```
>>> arcpy.sa.CostConnectivity(inputFC,inputRaster, arcpy.Geometry())
u'in_memory\\f7F3FF137_E474_4E4B_A77B_A0AD9C7851C0; '
```

Is there a way to correct this behavior and have it return the object I am looking for?

For example, a tool whose output is a feature class according to documentation, but outputting arcpy.Geometry() instead of a file returns a list of geometry objects:

```
>>> arcpy.SurfaceContour_3d(inputTIN,arcpy.Geometry(),1e23,0)
[<Polyline object at 0x22029350[0x21da3740]>, <Polyline object at 0x22029850[0x21da31e0]>]
```

Comment: You are correct, if you set the output to be `arcpy.Geometry()`  then it does indeed return a list of geometries! In all the years I've been using geoprocessing tools, never knew they had this functionality!  Stumbling around the help file does confirm this on this [page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/using-geometry-objects-with-geoprocessing-tools.htm). I suspect the implementation of this functionality is tool specific and probably something you can't change?